# Filtering entity framework dbset before assigning it as datasource

Tags: entity-framework, filtering, bindinglist

I want to be able to do what is commented out below but I can not figure out how to do so.  I understand why I need to do the load and then reference the local observable collection and set it to be a BindingList so that changes in the grid are kept in sync, but how can I do the filtering I want to do before assigning it?  As it is now, I need to do the filtering within the grid which is not what I want to do.

```
Core.MyContext.SiteVisits.Load();
var siteVisits = Core.MyContext.SiteVisits.Local.ToBindingList();
//.Where(siteVisit => siteVisit.UPC == _site.UPC)
ugSiteVisits.DataSource = siteVisits;
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Move the `Where` before the `Load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading all the SiteVisits, just query the ones you want and add them to a the Local collection with `IQueryable<T>.Load()`.

```
Core.MyContext.SiteVisits.Where(siteVisit => siteVisit.UPC == _site.UPC).Load();
ugSiteVisits.DataSource = Core.MyContext.SiteVisits.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I certainly tried that and of course, it doesn't work.  IQueryable does not support ToBindingList which is exactly my problem.  Sorry, no credit for your answer.

Comment: David, thanks so much for this info!  The new observablecollection method is exactly what I was missing and it works in my program.  I couldn't believe there wasn't a way to do this, you've restored my faith in EntityFramework/Linq.

Comment: Damn, it seems I need to retract my kudos for this.  I tested my app to change a field in a row in the dbset and that worked fine.  However, I deleted a row in a different test and the row isn't deleted in the database. I'm now suspecting that the AsEnumerable extension method isn't making the observablecollection sync with EF. Help please?

Comment: In my exhaustive efforts to figure this out, I found an extension method that was supposed to turn an ienumerable range into a bindinglist shown below.  This too didn't work because changes in the grid weren't reflected in the database and vice versa.

    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        return new BindingList<T>(range.ToList());
    }

Comment: See updated answer for an option to use the DbSet<T>.Local for binding.

Comment: The second solution works, the first does not.  Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Cool.  I had forgotten why the .Local was there in the first place :)